# float and int value subtraction in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I think following is related to precision of float values somehow, but I'm not sure how and why exactly following behavior is observed. I have following piece of code in java:

```
class float_int
{
    void float_to_int(float val)
    {
        int int_val = (int)val;
        float remain_val = val - (float)int_val;
        System.out.println("val - " + val);
        System.out.println("int_val - " + (float)int_val);
        System.out.println("remain_val - " + remain_val);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        float_int obj = new float_int();
        obj.float_to_int((float)12.345);
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
val - 12.345
int_val - 12.0
remain_val - 0.34500027
```

Now I'm not sure why I'm getting an extra "27" at the end for remain_val.

Comment: I suggest using `double` unless you have a *very good* reason.  You will still see these issues but they will be about one billion times smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because neither `12.345` nor `0.345` is exactly representable in binary floating-point.

[For example](http://ideone.com/OT8gLM):

```
float f = 12.345f;
System.out.printf("%.15f\n", f);  // Displays 12.345000267028809
```

In the above code, 12.345000267028809 is the nearest value that **is** exactly representable.

Comment: Any reason why "27" or is it just random?

Comment: @pkumar.. Just try to convert `0.345` to `base 2`, and you will get to know. Time to take out a pen and paper. Don't just believe any stranger.

Comment: @pkumar. And once you convert to base 2 successfully, it would be time to go through - `floating-point` tag wiki on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, it is because floats are not precise.

If you want your float to be represented correctly, you can use the same approach that this guy seemed to take: http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/java/

Which is to round the float:

```
String.format("%.2f", 1.2399) // returns "1.24"
String.format("%.3f", 1.2399) // returns "1.240"
String.format("%.2f", 1.2) // returns "1.20"
```